# The program refuses to go into the second statement

Tags: c++

I'm not too goood at programming, in fact i already started and gave myself a homework, feel free to say i'm a noob.

Here's the problem statement:

You can plant one of two seeds ( blue or red )
A red will grow into a flower when planted in soil temperatures above 75 degrees, otherwise, it will grow into a mushroom assuming the temperatur meets the confitions for growing a flower planting the red seed in wet soil will produce a sunflower and planting the red seed in dry soil will produce a dandiliom. 
A blue seed will gorw in a flower when in soil temps. from 60-70 F degrees. Or its a mushroom. in wet soil its a dandelion in dry

Here's the code:

*

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string plantedSeed = "";
    string seedColor = "";
    cout << "What color will the seed be? (red/blue): \n";
    getline(cin, seedColor);
    int soilTemperature = 0;
    cout << "What temperature will the soil have?\n";
    cin >> soilTemperature;
    if (seedColor == "red")
    {
        if (soilTemperature >= 75)
            plantedSeed = "mushroom";
        if (soilTemperature < 75)
        {
            string seedState = "";
            cout << "Enter the state of the soil in which the seed is plantet to (wet/dry)\n";
            getline(cin, seedState);
            if (seedState == "wet")
                plantedSeed = "sunflower";
            if (seedState == "dry")
                plantedSeed = "dandelion";
        }
    }
    if(seedColor == "blue")
    { 
        if (soilTemperature >= 60 && soilTemperature <= 70)
            plantedSeed = "mushroom";
        else
        {
            string seedState = "";
            cout << "Enter the state of the soil in which the seed is plantet to (wet/dry)\n";
            getline(cin, seedState);
            if (seedState == "wet")
                plantedSeed = "dandelion";
            if (seedState == "dry")
                plantedSeed = "sunflower";
        }
    }
    cout << "The planted seed has transformed into: " << endl;
    cout << plantedSeed << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

*
The problem is that the program refuses to go into the if(soilTemperature < 75) statement

```
if (seedColor == "red")
    {
        if (soilTemperature >= 75)
            plantedSeed = "mushroom";
        if (soilTemperature < 75)
        {
            string seedState = "";
            cout << "Enter the state of the soil in which the seed is plantet to (wet/dry)\n";
            getline(cin, seedState);
            if (seedState == "wet")
                plantedSeed = "sunflower";
            if (seedState == "dry")
                plantedSeed = "dandelion";
        }
    }
```

it's the same for blue.

Comment: use string comparision functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ignore the `\n`after reading temperature:

```
cout << "What temperature will the soil have?\n";
cin >> soilTemperature;
cin.ignore();
```

After reading temperature, you have this end-of-line in the standar input. Then, you read the emptly line in the following getline. Of course, you are wrong, the program gets into the second statement, but getline finishes directly with the empty line.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved a newbie.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common problem when mixing the use of `std::getline`, and `operator>>` to read from `std::cin`. `operator>>` has certain nuanced semantics when it comes to consuming input and skipping whitespace.

Although it is possible to do this correctly, it's better to avoid dealing with this headache in the first place.

Replace the code that reads the temperature with `std::getline` into a string, just like all the others. Construct a separate `std::istringstream` from that, and use `operator>>` on the `std::istringstream` to parse the temperature. Problem solved.

Comment: Thanks, but a simple cin.ignore(); saved me, altho i didn't know such a thing exists i now know.